# Where Can I Find My Zend Studio License Code

Tags: zend-studio

I purchased my Zend Studio license from Zend about 18 hours ago and have received the receipt email and can see the license numbers sitting in my Zend account, but I cannot find how to get my license code from that.

Anyone purchased a license for Zend Studio and can tell me what the process is to convert a license number into a license code?

Thanks

Edit #1
A check of the Zend Studio support page at http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio/content/registering_your_license.htm?Highlight=license shows that the instructions say that I need to go to the help menu and click on the Register link in order to enter my order number and license number, but when I check my Help menu this does not appear anywhere. The only place anything to do with a license is in the Zend Studio License window, but it is asking for a license key, and when I enter my license number, it says it is invalid.

Comment: Have you tried customer support? We aren't here for customer support for certain products

Comment: I have and I have been waiting for a response for the last 5 days from them. I am aware that customer support for certain products isn't the aim of SO but given the number of PHP developers on here I figured that there might be a few who use Zend Studio and may have gone through something similar who could advise me how they got around it.